# How to replace mislabeled dates in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I recently received a dataset with some dates and values that was scraped online. The problem is that some of the dates were not scraped properly. As a result, they turned up as hexes instead. One day is split into 48 intervals (as you can see in the second column), and the year (5th column), month (6th column), and name of the day is given.

Is there any way I can convert the hexes into properly labelled date in pandas? (I want to process this csv file into a pandas dataframe for time series analysis.)

[image of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vLS4.png)

Comment: My god, you're right. Thank you. I spent hours trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: you can thank me by accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue isn't related to the csv file content, the viewer you use (in this case i think its Excel) is just displaying it due to overflow in the cell... try to expand it a little